# Upload to Earth Engine from Google Drive on python

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-drive

I want to replicate the [python keras example](https://github.com/google/earthengine-api/blob/master/python/examples/ipynb/TF_demo1_keras.ipynb) on Colab but using Google Drive instead of Google Cloud. I was able to make it work for most of the code instead of the last part consisting of uploading the TFrecord and JSON file to EE, to visualize the results:

```
!earthengine upload image --asset_id={outputAssetID} {outputImageFile} {jsonFile}
```

This command line seems to only work with Cloud Storage Buckets and not with Drive. I also tried to manually upload the files to EE but I got the error:

> Manifests for TfRecord ingestion must have exactly one tileset with exactly one source.

I know that it is possible to fix this error using:

```
!earthengine --no-use_cloud_api upload image --asset_id={outputAssetID} {outputImageFile} {jsonFile}
```

Is there an alternative to this command line to upload from Drive or a local file from Colab?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible. Some years ago, Google said they didn't want to re-implement the Cloud Storage tools for managing uploads of large files. So unless something changed recently (and I haven't got any indication on that it has), if you want to get files from your local computer or from Drive into EE, you first have to upload it to Cloud Storage. And yes, that's really too bad.